# If $A$ is normal, then so is any polynomial of it.

Tags: linear-algebra

By normal, I mean $AA^T$=$A^TA$

Just wondering if this statement is true or false. I'm trying to use this statement to prove something else in my homework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually "normal" means that $AA^T=A^TA$ (for real matrices; for complex ones you would take conjugate transpose), $AA^T=I$ being refered to as orthogonality. Either way, did you try an example?

Comment: I'm sorry. I got the two things confused. You're correct.

Comment: To clear up the confusion could you edit the question to include which definition you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a normal matrix and $p$ a polynomial. Then $p(A)^T=p(A^T)$ since $(A^n)^T=(A^T)^n$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$ and $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ for matrices $A$ and $B$. To show that $p(A)$ is normal, we need to show $p(A)p(A)^T=p(A)^Tp(A)$, so by the above we just have to show $p(A)p(A^T)=p(A^T)p(A)$. This is easy enough because if $x$ and $y$ commute then $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ commute.

Comment: This is gold, I've gotten this statement to prove with a small (yet annoyingly annoying) change, here's the statement I need to prove:

if $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is normal, than for all $p[x]\in \mathbb{C}[x],p(A)$ is normal.

Since you used $A^t$ and not $A^*$, I'm uncertain weather this proof suffices, thoughts?

Comment: It's not too hard to adapt to $\mathbb C$. We want to show that $p(A)p(A)^*=p(A)^*p(A)$ when $AA^*=A^*A$. Note that $p(A)^*=\overline{p(A^*)}$, so we just want to show $p(A)\overline{p(A^*)}=\overline{p(A^*)}p(A)$. This holds because $A$ and $A^*$ commute, and the coefficients of the polynomials all commute.